readlines files in r with differents encoding
I have :
guess_encoding("file.txt")$encoding
[1] "UTF-8"      "ISO-8859-1" "ISO-8859-2"

I want to read my file :
lines <- readLines("file.txt", encoding = guess_encoding("file.txt")$encoding)

but it return this error
Error in readLines("file.txt", encoding = guess_encoding("file.txt")$encoding) : 
  invalid 'encoding' value


you showed that guess_encoding (from readr) made 3 guesses
"UTF-8" "ISO-8859-1" "ISO-8859-2"

to pick the first guess and try to use it would be

 lines <- readLines("file.txt", encoding = guess_encoding("file.txt")$encoding[[1]])

